# Update recycler when type word in edittext (search)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I want when write a word in edit text my recycler updated , but when i write for example (sample) my list is equal word(sa) and (sample) .
I use volley to get data from server .
my code :

```
public void get_search(String text) {
    JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, G.url_search + text, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    try {
                        Job job = new Job();
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        int job_lat = jsonObject.getInt("job_lat");
                        job.setJob_lng(job_lng);
                        list.add(job);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    jobAdapter.setData(list);
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
searchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Log.i("log", "onTextChanged: " + charSequence.toString());
                get_search(charSequence.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
```

and my adapter code :

```
   public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.ViewHolder> {
  private Context context;
  private List<Job> list;

  public SearchAdapter(Context context, List<Job> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;

  }
public void setData(List<Job> list){
this.list = list;
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

```
  @Override
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.search_index,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Job job = list.get(position);
    holder.job_owner.setText(job.getJob_title());

  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
  }

  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView job_owner;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      job_owner = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    }
  }
}
```

ok i well hope understand my question should use notifyDataSetChanged but i do not where use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need setData method in your adapter

```
public void setData(List<Job> list){
this.list = list;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In your `jsonObjectRequest onResponse`

```
adapter.setData(list);
```

add `list.clear()` first line in your `onresponse`

Comment: ok exactlly where use this code <adapter.setData(list)> show me please

Comment: replace `recyclerView.setAdapter(jobAdapter) jobAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` with  `adapter.setData(list);`

Comment: where is get_search(charSequence.toString()); ?

Comment: get_search is jsonrequest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176514/discussion-between-prashant17-and-hadi-khezrpor).

Answer (score 0):

I think we should:

- implement the **get_search** function
- after the composing the new result we have to update the adapter by calling the **notifyDataSetChanged**

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

add this code to first line response 
list.clear();
and it work 
thank for @prashant17